# Вес селекторов в Angular

Tags: angular8, styled-components

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он не стал красний, не понимаю почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждому элементу селектора ангуляр добавляет селектор аттрибута компонента для изоляции стилей.

[Специфичность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

[Онлайн калькулятор](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/* In angular:  
.color {color: red;}
div div {color: green;}
*/

.color[_ngcontent-dnf-c20] {color: red;}
div[_ngcontent-dnf-c20] div[_ngcontent-dnf-c20] {color: green;}


/* In angular:  
div div.color {color: red;}
div div {color: green;}
*/
div[_ngcontent-dnf-c21] div.color[_ngcontent-dnf-c21] {color: red;}
div[_ngcontent-dnf-c21] div[_ngcontent-dnf-c21] {color: green;}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-dnf-c20>
  <div _ngcontent-dnf-c20 class=color>Color</div>
</div>

<div _ngcontent-dnf-c21>
  <div _ngcontent-dnf-c21 class=color>Color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: div div какая тогда селективнось?. Если клас имеет 10. Я когда стиль задаю просто не в компоненте ангуляра то он красний. А в ангуляре он зеленый

Comment: div div = 2(низшего приорите), .color = 1 (второго приортитета(классы))

Comment: Понял почему, обновил ответ

Comment: Да, понял, просто несколько дней ни был у ноутбука. Спасибо